# Replace tab & new line feed with empty string in JSON string

Tags: php, json

I have a **JSON** string which is like this when I log it:

```
..."items":{"0":"
\t\t\t\t\t"},"buys":{"0":"
\t\t\t\t\t"}}}, "sells":{}, "clients":{"test":{"0":"
\t\t\t\t"}...
```

What I want is to delete all `new line feed (\n) & tab characters(\t)` from it and have a **JSON** string like this :

```
..."items":{},"buys":{}}}, "sells":{}, "clients":{"test":{}...
```

I have written a `preg_replace` function like this :

```
$json = preg_replace(['/\"0\"\:\n\"[\\t]+/'], [''], $json);
```

but When I log the **JSON** string they have not been deleted .

What should I do ?

Comment: `json_decode($yourString )` it will do the rest. i think but it is not tested yet

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I have tested it but the space remains

Comment: Can you post a full sample json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace()` function to replace the `\t` and `\n`:

```
$json = str_replace(array('\t','\n'),'',$json);
```

You can read more about this ***[here](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.str-replace.php)***.

Comment: it worked. Thanks . but Why preg_replace does not work ?

Comment: @Ramin, awesome, I'm not that good with regex but I think using `preg_replace` would work if you do something like `/(\\\\n|\\\\t)/` ... `preg_replace('/(\\\\n|\\\\t)/', '', $json);`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regular expression

```
"[\t\n\r]"
```